# Implementing a closed loop in verilog

Tags: loops, verilog

I'm trying to implement a loop without using loop instructions in verilog so i made a counter module and the simulation went perfectly but when i tried to implement it on the FPGA i got a lot of errors in the mapping , like this one

```
ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT4 symbol
"Inst_Count/Mcompar_GND_1105_o_xcount[7]_LessThan_25_o_lut<0>" (output
signal=Inst_Count/Mcompar_GND_1105_o_xcount[7]_LessThan_25_o_lut<0>) has
input signal "Inst_Count/Madd_x[9]_GND_1105_o_add_0_OUT_cy<0>" which will be
trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map Report File for details about why the input
signal will become undriven.
```

These errors only occurred when i replaced this module with the loop instruction module so does anyone no what's the problem with this one ?

Thanks for giving this your time :)

```
module average( input rst , output reg [7:0]
reg [7:0] count;
reg [7:0] prv_count;

reg clk;

initial
begin

count = 8'd0;

end

always @ (posedge rst)
begin

clk = 1'b0;

end

always @ (clk)
begin

prv_count = count ;
count = prv_count + 1'b1;

end

always @ (count)
begin

if (count == 8'd255)
G_count= count;
else
begin

clk = ~clk;
G_count= count;

end

end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this is just plain wrong. I don't really think anybody can help here without giving you a lecture on Verilog, but... some things that are noticeable right away are:

1. You have an obvious syntax error in your module parameter list where you do not close it (i.e. `)` went missing).
2. Clock should be an input to your module. Even if you depend on reset input only and use a register as a "clock", it won't work (logically and you have combinatorial loop that must be broken or else...).
3. Do not use initial block in the code that should be synthesizable.
4. `prv_count` is useless.
5. No need to manually take care of the overflow (check for 255? `8'd255` is exactly `8'b11111111` and it resets to 0 if you add 1'b1, etc).

And tons of other things, which raise the obvious question — have you tried reading some books on Verilog, preferably those covering synthesizable part of the language? :) Anyhow, what you are trying to do (as far as I can understand) would probably look something like this:

```
module average(input clk, input rst, output reg [7:0] overflow_count);
   reg [7:0] count;

   always @(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
      if (~rst) begin
         count <= 8'b0;
         overflow_count <= 8'b0;
      end else begin
         count <= (count + 1'b1);
         if (count == 8'b0)
           overflow_count <= (overflow_count + 1'b1);
      end
   end
endmodule
```

Hope it helps and really suggest you take a look at some good books on HDL.

Comment: Well my verilog knowledge is a collection of advises and part 1 of a book named Verilog HDL since i can only afford one .I'm rushing my work to meet a deadline this Saturday but once i'm done i'll take my time with it because working with the FPGA is really fun :)

Thanks my friend and i really appreciate your honesty :)